# Were I can find Chart Controls tutorial for WPF of .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I found the following Chart Control tutorial for Windows Form is very useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

However, I am not able to find the corresponding tutorial for WPF.

Does it even exist in MSDN?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find it myself... it seems its Work-In-Progress ([for a long time now](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/58833?ProjectName=wpf)). The only lead I could find on WPF Charts was on [Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx). He has a sample application with diff possibilities - however it's not easy to pick up. Also the dll version in the samples is different (has more types/functionality) from what comes with the WPF toolkit download

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking only for charts .Net framework provide.. take a look at [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/3rdPartyLibs.html) see the options available under charts.. you can find chart providers and nice tutorials

One very famous option for charting is WPF toolkit. You can download sample code demonstrating all charts from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The best sources of information for charting on WPF are Delay's MSDN blog and the data visualization demos that accompany the charting library releases.  Here is the page that describes the charting releases and links to the demos:

- [Two birds, squared! (Silverlight/WPF Data Visualization Development Release 3 and a DataVisualizationDemos update)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/30/two-birds-squared-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-3-and-a-datavisualizationdemos-update.aspx)

You can also search the MSDN blogs for charting to find many specific tutorials, mostly by Delay:

- [MSDN Blogs > Search > "charting"](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=charting&sections=6092)